# C#: ошибка using Windows.Security

Tags: c#

**Добрый день.**

Столкнулся с задачей генерации MAC для ISO8583, мне один добрый человек подсказал класс [MacAlgorithmProvider class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.security.cryptography.core.macalgorithmprovider.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1).Я делаю как в примере, но вот что получается, когда я пишу:

```
using Windows.Security.Cryptography;
using Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
```

VS ругается на "Windows" - пишет, мол, может я ссылку пропустил.

Я хотел ссылку добавить через "Добавить ссылку" к контекстном меню к проекту, но там не было такого.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить эту ошибку. Спасибо.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартный MacAlgorithmProvider действительно требует операционную систему не ниже Windows 8, но возможно вам подойдет библиотека [PCLCrypto](https://github.com/AArnott/PCLCrypto). Она доступна в NuGet практически для всех платформ, и в ней есть свой MacAlgorithmProvider. Ее API основан на аналогичных API из WinRT.

Пример генерации MAC:

```
byte[] keyMaterial;
byte[] data;
var algorithm = WinRTCrypto.MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(MacAlgorithm.HmacSha1);
CryptographicHash hasher = algorithm.CreateHash(keyMaterial);
hasher.Append(data);
byte[] mac = hasher.GetValueAndReset();
string macBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(mac);
```

Более подробно здесь: [wiki](https://github.com/AArnott/PCLCrypto/wiki/Crypto-Recipes)

Answer (score 3):

Судя по описанию на MSDN этот метод относится к пространству имен

```
Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core
```

находящемуся в сборке с аналогичным названием. А сборка эта поставляется  начиная с Windows 8 и Windows Server 2012. Вероятно, на вашей машине стоит Win7 или ниже, а потому таковой сборки у вас просто нет. 
К сожалению точно утверждать не могу, поскольку проверить сейчас возможности нет - сам в данный момент сижу за Win7

Answer (score 3):

Выглядит так, как будто этот класс - из WinRT. Если вы пишете под какую-то другую платформу, неудивительно, что не можете найти нужную сборку.