# C#: генерация MAC для ISO8583 по двум ключам

Tags: c#, стандарт, iso

Добрый день.

Столкнулся с интересной задачей - реализую протокол ISO8583, дошел до последнего пункта -требуется сформировать **МАС** (ключ авторизации сообщения).
Известно, что будут даваться два КОМПОНЕНТА ключа (**А** и **В**), алгоритм: **ANSI X9.19 retail MAC**.

**Подскажите пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать? Может кто-то сталкивался с этим?**

Использую Windows 7, поэтому класс "MacAlgorithmProvider class" использовать не могу.

Comment: Вот здесь случаем не тот же вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416455/c-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-using-windows-security

Comment: Нет не тот же. Разница в том, что в этом вопросе указано что у нас 2 ключа (2 части одного ключа).

Answer (score 2):

вам сможет помочь bouncycastle: http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/
(bouncycastle.crypto.macs.ISO9797Alg3Mac)

Comment: у вас случайно примера реализации ISO9797Alg3Mac нету?